# How to add support for the exponential operator to one of the boost::spirit calculators?

Tags: c++, boost, grammar, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to add the exponential operator to this boost::spirit calculator [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/calc8/), whose grammar is the one below. Note that expressions like "-2^2^3" must be parsed as "-(2^(2^3))" == -256.

> ```
>     expr =
>         equality_expr.alias()
>         ;
>
>     equality_expr =
>             relational_expr
>         >> *(equality_op > relational_expr)
>         ;
>
>     relational_expr =
>             logical_expr
>         >> *(relational_op > logical_expr)
>         ;
>
>     logical_expr =
>             additive_expr
>         >> *(logical_op > additive_expr)
>         ;
>
>     additive_expr =
>             multiplicative_expr
>         >> *(additive_op > multiplicative_expr)
>         ;
>
>     multiplicative_expr =
>             unary_expr
>         >> *(multiplicative_op > unary_expr)
>         ;
>
>     unary_expr =
>             primary_expr
>         |   (unary_op > primary_expr)
>         ;
>
>     primary_expr =
>             uint_
>         |   identifier
>         |   bool_
>         |   '(' > expr > ')'
>         ;
>
>     identifier =
>             !keywords
>         >>  raw[lexeme[(alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_')]]
>         ;
> ```

After having read the documentation, my understanding is that I have to insert the following exponential_expr rule to the grammar for it to parse exponential operations with the proper right-to-left associativity:

> ```
>     multiplicative_expr =
>             exponential_expr
>         >> *(multiplicative_op > exponential_expr)
>         ;
>
>     exponential_expr =
>             unary_expr
>         >> !(exponential_op >> exponential_expr)
>         ;
> ```

Where the rules are:

```
    qi::rule<Iterator, ast::expression(), ascii::space_type>
    expr, equality_expr, relational_expr,
    logical_expr, additive_expr, multiplicative_expr, exponential_expr
    ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, ast::operand(), ascii::space_type>
    unary_expr, primary_expr
    ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, ast::function_call(), ascii::space_type >
    function_call
    ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::list<ast::expression>(), ascii::space_type >
    argument_list
    ;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type>
    identifier
    ;

    qi::symbols<char, ast::optoken>
    equality_op, relational_op, logical_op,
    additive_op, multiplicative_op, unary_op, exponential_op
    ;

    qi::symbols<char>
    keywords
    ;
```

The problem I am having now is that the program fails to compile, as the AST ([ast.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/calc8/ast.hpp)) must be also modified accordingly, but I don't exactly now how. Do you have any idea?

This is the compiler error:

> calculator/ExpressionDef.hpp:114:9:   required from
>   'calculator::parser::expression::expression(calculator::error_handler&)
>   [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >]' Expression.cpp:4:37:   required from here
>   /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:152:13: error:
>   no matching function for call to
>   'calculator::ast::expression::expression(const
>   boost::variant,
>   boost::recursive_wrapper,
>   boost::recursive_wrapper >&)'
>   /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:152:13: note:
>   candidates are: In file included from
>   ./calculator/Expression.hpp:20:0,
>                    from calculator/ExpressionDef.hpp:1,
>                    from Expression.cpp:1: ./calculator/Ast.hpp:83:12: note: calculator::ast::expression::expression()
>   ./calculator/Ast.hpp:83:12: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1
>   provided ./calculator/Ast.hpp:83:12: note:
>   calculator::ast::expression::expression(const
>   calculator::ast::expression&) ./calculator/Ast.hpp:83:12: note:   no
>   known conversion for argument 1 from 'const
>   boost::variant,
>   boost::recursive_wrapper,
>   boost::recursive_wrapper >' to 'const
>   calculator::ast::expression&' ./calculator/Ast.hpp:83:12: note:
>   calculator::ast::expression::expression(calculator::ast::expression&&)
>   ./calculator/Ast.hpp:83:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1
>   from 'const boost::variant,
>   boost::recursive_wrapper,
>   boost::recursive_wrapper >' to
>   'calculator::ast::expression&&'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it thoroughly but I think that the following modifications provide the functionality you want. Keep in mind that this version of the calculator uses ints as its only type, and so you won't be able to work with negative exponents and the danger of overflow is present.

1. **ast.hpp**
   You need to add a new element (`op_exp`) to the enum `optoken`:

   ```
   ...
   op_times,
   op_divides,
   op_exp,    //ADDED //Line 55
   op_positive,
   ...
   ```
2. **expression.hpp**
   You need to add a declaration for `exponential_expr`, `exponential_operand` and `exponential_op`:

   ```
   qi::rule<Iterator, ast::expression(), ascii::space_type>
       expr, equality_expr, relational_expr,
       logical_expr, additive_expr, multiplicative_expr, exponential_expr //MODIFIED
       ;

   qi::rule<Iterator, ast::operand(), ascii::space_type>
       unary_expr, primary_expr, exponential_operand //MODIFIED
       ;
   ...
   qi::symbols<char, ast::optoken>
       equality_op, relational_op, logical_op,
       additive_op, multiplicative_op, exponential_op, unary_op //MODIFIED
       ;
   ```
3. **expression_def.hpp**
   You need to add the initialization of `exponential_op`, change the rules as follows, and add the new rules to the list of `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES`:

   ```
   ...
   multiplicative_op.add
       ("*", ast::op_times)
       ("/", ast::op_divide)
       ;       
   exponential_op.add      //ADDED //Line 69
   ("^", ast::op_exp)
   ;
   ...
   multiplicative_expr =       
           unary_expr
       >> *(multiplicative_op > unary_expr)
       ;

   unary_expr =    //MODIFIED
           exponential_operand
       |   (unary_op > exponential_operand)
       ;

   exponential_operand = exponential_expr; //ADDED

   exponential_expr =          //ADDED
           primary_expr
       >> *(exponential_op > unary_expr)
       ;

   primary_expr =
           uint_
       |   identifier
       |   bool_
       |   '(' > expr > ')'
       ;
   ...
   (additive_expr)
   (multiplicative_expr)
   (exponential_expr)      //ADDED //Line 150
   (exponential_operand)   //ADDED
   (unary_expr)
   ...
   ```
4. **compiler.cpp**
   You need to add a new case to the switches in `program::print_assembler` and `compiler::operator()`:

   ```
   ...
   case op_div:
       line += "      op_div";
       break;

   case op_exp:        //ADDED //Line 105
       line += "      op_exp";
       break;

   case op_eq:
       line += "      op_eq";
       break;
   ...
   case ast::op_times: program.op(op_mul); break;
   case ast::op_divide: program.op(op_div); break;
   case ast::op_exp: program.op(op_exp); break;  //ADDED //Line 244

   case ast::op_equal: program.op(op_eq); break;
   ...
   ```
5. **vm.hpp**
   You need to add a new element (`op_exp`) to the enum `byte_code`:

   ```
   ...
   op_mul,         //  multiply top two stack entries
   op_div,         //  divide top two stack entries
   op_exp,         //ADDED //Line 24

   op_not,         //  boolean negate the top stack entry
   ...
   ```
6. **vm.cpp**
   You need to add a new case to the switch in `vmachine::execute` (I've simply used std::pow, including cmath previously):

   ```
   ...
   case op_div:
       --stack_ptr;
       stack_ptr[-1] /= stack_ptr[0];
       break;

   case op_exp:    //ADDED //Line 60
       --stack_ptr;
       stack_ptr[-1] = std::pow(stack_ptr[-1],stack_ptr[0]);
       break;

   case op_eq:
       --stack_ptr;
       stack_ptr[-1] = bool(stack_ptr[-1] == stack_ptr[0]);
       break;
   ...
   ```

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4774f9b605937e75) you can find a modification of `calc6.cpp` (the last compiler example that fits in a single cpp file) that does the same (with awfully named rules and a hardcoded expression).

Comment: I ll test it in a moment, just let me say that I seem to have done the same thing after some time of work and given that grammar expressions like "-2^2^3" are parsed as (-2)^(2^3) and not as -(2^(2^3)) as it should be. I ll confirm this as soon as possible.

Comment: Also note that calc6 has a different grammar from calc8. The latter is the one I need help on. Basically the expoential_expr rules comes before unary_expr, so the grammar you proposed for calc8 parses the above example wrongly as (-2)^[...]. calc6 seems to be fine, but it's another calculator. By the way, didn't you mean to write "exponential_expr = unary_expr >> *(exponential_op > exponential_expr) ?

Comment: In its current state the grammar gives a greater precedence to the unary- vs the exponentiation operator, but that is just an oversight on my part and I think that it is (moderately) easily reversed (I'll try). I'm not certain about your question about the exponential_expr but I think that what I used is right.

Comment: Added new changes to "expression.hpp" and "expression_def.hpp". I believe that it works, but you should test it thoroughly.

Comment: I was also wrong about your question about `exponential_expr` with my previous grammar only numbers, identifiers and expression in parenthesis were valid exponents. I think that the current grammar matches the [behaviour of python](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator).

Comment: It does not work, with the solution  you proposed expressions like "-2^2^2" are wrongly parsed as ((-2)^2)^2), but it must be correctly parsed following math rules, that is as "-(2^(2^2))" == 256

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the result should be -16

Comment: Sorry it works, it was my implementation accepting qi::double_type as primary_expr instead of uint, so -2 was parsed as double_type. for me the fix is to use an unsigned double_type, which does not exist in boost::spirit::qi

Comment: It does exist, you can find it [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/real.html). I think you can simply use `qi::real_parser<double, qi::ureal_policies<double> > udouble_;` but I don't have experience with that. I feel using `unary_expr =(unary_op > exponential_operand) | exponential_operand;` should also work.